# Set variable false after executing a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this code and inside it I set the variable "showLoading" to true to show the user that the page is loading. Sometimes loading takes a long time to finish. How do I set the variable to false again when it finishes loading? Please give me a simple way since ive started coding javascript + angular weeks ago.

HTML inside the table:

```
<th scope="col" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Organize por data!" 
    class="table-pointer" ng-click='sortColumn("DATA_VENDA")'
    ng-class='sortClass("DATA_VENDA")'>
  Data
</th>
```

SCRIPT:

```
// column to sort
$scope.column = 'Data';
// sort ordering (Ascending or Descending). Set true for descending
$scope.reverse = false; 
// called on header click
$scope.sortColumn = function(col){
    $scope.showLoading = false;
    $scope.column = col;
    if($scope.reverse){
        $scope.reverse = false;
        $scope.reverseclass = 'arrow-up';
    }else{
        $scope.reverse = true;
        $scope.reverseclass = 'arrow-down';
    }
};
// remove and change class
$scope.sortClass = function(col){
    if($scope.column == col){
        if($scope.reverse){
            return 'arrow-down'; 
        }else{
            return 'arrow-up';
        }
    }else{
        return '';
    }
}
```

---

## Update

In another part of the code i did this, but i dont know how to apply for the function in the example..

```
$scope.enjuListBackPecafunction = function() {
    $scope.mostrarLoading = true;
    return $scope.enjuListBackPeca = Peca.query({
        dateFromPeca:'20170101',
        dateToPeca:'20180830'
        // dateToPeca: $scope.endDate
    }, function (err, values) {
        $scope.mostrarLoading = false;
        if (err) return err;
        return values
    });
};
```

Comment: When asking a question about a problem caused by your code, you will get much better answers if you provide code people can use to reproduce the problem. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Thanks, already updated...

Comment: The code here is not doing the page loading. There is a watcher somewhere that is watching `$scope.reverse` and invoking a function that does the page loading. Is this done in a third-party library or in your own code?

Comment: Is `Peca.query` a third-party library? If so, its callback operates outside the AngularJS execution context. If `Peca.query` is a $resource object, the callback is wrong.

Comment: the "$scope.mostrarLoading = true" just shows a div in the HTML that contains the sentence "waiting, loading...". What i want to do is hide this div when the function finishes its job

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because because there is not enough information to reproduce the problem and it is unclear what you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you want to have a Promise that controls the process that "sometimes takes a long time to finish". Let's imaging there is a method that implements asynchronous sorting:

```
var doSortAsync = function(column, order) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve) {
    // ... sending a sort request with column-order params
    // ... getting the result asynchronously
    // ... and calling the resolve method when it is done
    resolve(result);
  })
}
```

Then you just call it in your controller method with appropriate params:

```
$scope.sortColumn = function(col) {
  $scope.showLoading = true;
  $scope.column = col;
  if($scope.reverse) {
    $scope.reverse = false;
    $scope.reverseclass = 'arrow-up';
  } else {
    $scope.reverse = true;
    $scope.reverseclass = 'arrow-down';
  }
  doSortAsync(col, $scope.reverse).then(function(result) {
    $scope.showLoading = false;
  });
};
```

You need to know the exact moment when the process is done, and using Promise is a common approach here. In case you can't use ES6 Promises you may try AngularJS [$q service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q).

Comment: ES6 promises are not integrated with the AngularJS execution context. Only operations which are applied in the AngularJS execution context will benefit from AngularJS data-binding, exception handling, property watching, etc.

Comment: Too complex for me yet.. Sorry, im looking for a simple way...Just started javascript coding.

Comment: @HugoAroeira That's it, handling async stuff requires some complexity. I would recommend you to start investigate promise, deffered, async/await, observable and other async patterns.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `.finally` method of the promise to stop the spinner:

```
$scope.showLoading = true;

$http.get(url)
  .then(function(response) {
    $scope.data = response.data;
}).catch(function(response) {
    console.log(response.status);
    throw response;
}).finally(function() {
    $scope.showLoading = false;
});
```

The `.finally` block will always execute after the server responds either with the data or an error.

Answer (score 0):

I am quessing that `Peca.query` is a third-party callback-based API. To integrate it with the AngularJS framework, use [$q.defer](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#the-deferred-api):

```
function ajsPecaQuery(options) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    var resource = Peca.query(options, function (err, values) {
        if (err) return deferred.reject(err);
        //else
        return resolve(values);
    });
    resource.$promise = deferred.promise;
    return resource;
}
```

The function invokes the `Peca.query` operation and creates an AngularJS promise from the callback. It attaches the promise to the resource object with the property name `$promise`.

Then use it as so:

```
$scope.enjuListBackPecafunction = function() {
    $scope.mostrarLoading = true;
    var resource = ajsPecaQuery({
        dateFromPeca:'20170101',
        dateToPeca:'20180830'
        // dateToPeca: $scope.endDate
    });
    resource.$promise.finally(function() {
        $scope.mostrarLoading = false;
    });

    return $scope.enjuListBackPeca = resource;
};
```

The function starts the spinner at the beginning of the operation. It uses the `.finally` method of the promise to stop the spinner.

Don't forget to inject the `$q` service.

Comment: actually the UPDATE function works...i just want to apply it for the code in the example.